# If X and Y are two iid random variables, why $E[X|X+2Y] = E[Y|X + 2Y]$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

If X and Y are two iid random variables, why $E[X|X+2Y] = E[Y|X + 2Y]$?

I can see that $E[X|X+Y] = E[Y|X + Y]$, but if there is a coefficient, why it's true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who told you that? It's wrong.

Take for instance $X,Y\in\{0,1\}$. The map $(x,y)\in\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}\mapsto 
x+2y\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ being a bijection, we have $\sigma(X+2Y)=\sigma(X,Y)$, hence  $\mathbb E[X\vert X+2Y]=X$ and $\mathbb E[Y\vert X+2Y]=Y$.

Comment: Oh thanks! I was trying to find $E[Y|X + 3Y = 1500]$ give that $X, Y\sim N(250,125)$. Somebody suggested me using $E[Y|X + 3Y] = E[X|X + 3Y]$ and $E[X + 3Y|X + 3Y] = X + 3Y$ to derive an answer. I don't think the first equation makes sense (as you pointed out), and I think the right way to do is just to use conditional distribution of multivariate normal distribution, but surprisingly using the incorrect fact, we arrive at a correct answer, so I thought it could be correct.

Comment: I like your example, too! It shows that, although we know there exist functions $f(\cdot)$, $g(\cdot)$ such that $$\mathbf{E}[X\mid X+2Y]=f(X+2Y)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \mathbf{E}[Y\mid X+2Y]=g(X+2Y),$$ those 
$f$ and $g$ can be for more complicated than mere linear functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another counter-example.

Let $X, Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ be i.i.d. standard normal variables. Since $X+2Y$ and $2X-Y$ are jointly normal and uncorrelated, they are independent. This means that

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[X+2Y \mid X+2Y] &= X+2Y, \\
\mathbf{E}[2X-Y \mid X+2Y] &= \mathbf{E}[2X-Y] = 0.
\end{align*}

Solving this for $\mathbf{E}[X \mid X+2Y]$ and $\mathbf{E}[Y \mid X+2Y]$, we get

$$ \mathbf{E}[X \mid X+2Y] = \frac{X+2Y}{5}, \qquad \mathbf{E}[Y \mid X+2Y] = \frac{2(X+2Y)}{5}. $$

Comment: Beautiful fact actually! +1

Comment: I like your example because I was wondering whether something special could happen for centred variables.